# css hacks vs psd slicing

Tags: css

I just got into web development 2 months ago for a personal project. I am know facing an issue for which I would appreciate some advice of experienced people. In my project, I am using a lot css3 "effects": border-radius, box-shadows, gradients,etc. The thing is, I am now confronted to cross-browser issues. So my question is simple. Is it better to apply css hacks or use images (psd slicing)? Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to do a combination of both. PSD slicing will make it harder to update and maintain, whereas hacks don't usually get you what you want. Check out http://css3pie.com/ to see how you can incorporate most of the CSS3 techniques with IE. It's a great resource and I use it every day. It only works well for some items though, like drop shadow doesn't work well with PIE. For something like that you might do a background image of a drop shadow.

Comment: Hello thepriebe. Thanks for the link. This will help I guess. When you say drop shadow doesn't work well, do you mean box-shadow?

Comment: Precisely. I said drop shadow because I was referring to what most image editors call it. If you're using GIMP or Photoshop you'll find it called drop-shadow instead of how CSS refers to it: box-shadow.

Answer (score 1):

If you use some psd slicing make sure that the people that are visiting your website will not have any issues with slow loading. Truth be told, lots of people have a decent internet connection now so having a few more psd slicing will not be a problem.

Just make sure your images are well optimised for web and that should do the trick !

Comment: Hello dav. I will give a shot to this css pie suggested by thepriebe. Thanks anyway for the help..

Answer (score 1):

There are certainly items that you can use images for, but above all else, you are better off embracing the principals of progressive enhancement and making something that is compliant with current web standards.  Older browsers are slowly going away, but web standards are not.

Ensure that all visitors to the site are able to access the most important parts of the site.  Parts of the site may need to gracefully degrade and hide some features that are mainly aesthetic.  You can then apply appropriate fixes for those areas that could either be CSS hacks or images (for example, drop shadows and gradients).